# Process lots of images using AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, python-imaging-library, anaconda

I have a lot of images 100K+ stored in S3, and I have some code using pySpark to process some of them. I am using Anaconda Python so tons of libraries have already been properly installed, I am using the library `scipy`, `PIL` for images processing.

I am planning to use EMR, but here are my options:

1. How do I properly install all the libraries without too much hassle on the cluster:

> For Python applications, simply pass a .py file in the place of
>    instead of a JAR, and add Python .zip, .egg or .py
>   files to the search path with --py-files. - [Spark Documentation]

2. They also support [customized bootstrap](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#CustombootstrapCLI) to install software while provisioning the cluster. However, it turned out the linux installation of Anaconda is not as easy as 'yum install -y'. The installation involves:

   - download anacondaxxx.sh
   - bash anacondaxxx.sh
   - #answer 4 or 5 questions interactively
   - ..

Can anyone point me to the right direction what is a better way to bring up a cluster with Spark and Anaconda Python (or at least scipy and PIL) installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [EMR bootstrap actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) to do a [silent install of anaconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/help/silent.html)?

You might also want to consider Lambda as it now supports Python (2.7). Given that the files are already in S3, you'd need to script Lambda events for them.